# Detect duplicated rows with group by statement

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

To Detecting duplicated rows in my table i have this query :

```
select SeatForShowtimeID_FK,count(*) as cnt from dbo.TicketRow
group by SeatForShowtimeID_FK 
having cnt>1
```

I want to find row that have same `SeatForShowtimeID_FK`, but when i execute this query i get this error :

```
Invalid column name 'cnt'.
```

What should i do for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change `having cnt > 1` to `having count(*) > 1`

Comment: upvote, but there is no performance difference between count(*) and count(1).

Answer (score 1):

HAVING clause is WHERE clause of GROUP BY.
In HAVING you can't use alias of field.

You have written:

```
having cnt>1
```

but cnt is an alias. Your condition must be COUNT(*)>1 (or COUNT(1) as suggested by Moho).